# Getting net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Angular 7 App

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular7, ngrx, angular-httpclient

I am getting intermittently "net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR" for one of the API call in Angular 7 application, I am using ngrx also. All other API calls are working fine with the same configurations/headers

[image: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR]

Comment: Could you provide some of the code in the `error-handling.service.ts` ?

Comment: Sure @Korte, this is our custom error handling service in Angular.

  catchEffectError<T = Action>(...actions: Action[]): OperatorFunction<T, T | Action> {
    const handler = (error: Error): Action[] => {
      try {
        console.error('Error caught in effect\n', error);
      } catch (e) { }

      return [
        ...actions,
        this.notificationMessages.Error(),
        new ErrorsPushAction(error.toString()),
      ];
    }

Comment: @Joshi any luck solving this?

Comment: No @Obaid, I am not able to find the root cause for this, I just added 500ms delay for failing HTTP ajax call and now I am not getting these error. I am suspecting due to multiple HTTP calls, some HTTP call might be cancelling the effect of other http calls

Comment: I have the same issue in my app. I do multiple HTTP calls, and sometimes cancel some of them. When I do this, I get a lot of `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in Chrome. If you find a solution, please share it :)

Comment: @Dorian Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Yang, I'm sorry but no. I opened an issue on Github for this issue with example and reproductible case : https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/190 . According the creator of mod_h2 (on Nov 4, 2019) : "Chrome is not meeting the spec and had issues with other HTTP/2 implementations as well. They will fix this in the next canaries.". I check 5 minutes ago, it's still not fixed… In my company we retry the request after this failure as workaround, it's ugly but it's transparent for our end users :(